# Keep storing of the variable value with the recursive call

Tags: java, recursion

I have the contains method below to check whether a word is available in the radix trie data structure. To find the word I am using here the recursiv call of the method `contains`. But I am facing problem with this procedure to store the boolean variable `available` as `true` when it was found since when I move up the value of the varialbe `available` is being changed to false.

How can I keep the true value in the `available` variable if it was assigned to true once?

**Code:**

```
private boolean contains(TrieNode node, String s) {
    boolean available = false;
    String communsubString = checkEdgeString(node.getNext(), s);
    String restString = s.substring(communsubString.length());
    if (node.getNext() != null && !node.getNext().isEmpty()) {
        for (TrieNode nextNodeEdge : node.getNext()) {
            if (nextNodeEdge.getEdge().equals(communsubString)) {
                if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
                    contains(nextNodeEdge, restString);

                } else { 
                    // I want to keep the true value if I was here once.
                    available = true;
                }


            }

        }
    }
    return available;
}
```

Comment: Simply pass the value in method call itself, do not declare inside, make default as `false`

Comment: Why not simply `return true` instead of `available = true`?

Comment: You are discarding the return value of the recursive call. Also if available set to true in the for loop, you might `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've found something you can return true all the way up:

```
private boolean contains(TrieNode node, String s) {
String communsubString = checkEdgeString(node.getNext(), s);
String restString = s.substring(communsubString.length());
if (node.getNext() != null && !node.getNext().isEmpty()) {
    for (TrieNode nextNodeEdge : node.getNext()) {
        if (nextNodeEdge.getEdge().equals(communsubString)) {
            if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
                if ( contains(nextNodeEdge, restString) ) {
                      return true;
                }

            } else { 
                return true;
            }


        }

    }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can OR your current value of `available` with the result of the call to `contains`:

```
available |= contains(nextNodeEdge, restString);
```

You can then likely do some sort of fast-break to return more quickly, so you don't have to keep checking other nodes, since they can never make the value false:

```
if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
  available |= contains(nextNodeEdge, restString);
} else { 
  // I want to keep the true value if I was here once.
  available = true;
}
if (available) break;
```

or, more concisely:

```
if (restString.isEmpty() || contains(nextNodeEdge, restString)) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your recursive method which returns a `boolean` itself, why store the `available` in the first place? Why not simply `return` the value, like this:

```
private boolean contains(TrieNode node, String s) {
    var available = false;
    String communsubString = checkEdgeString(node.getNext(), s);
    String restString = s.substring(communsubString.length());
    if (node.getNext() != null && !node.getNext().isEmpty()) {
        for (TrieNode nextNodeEdge : node.getNext()) {
            if (nextNodeEdge.getEdge().equals(communsubString)) {
                if (!restString.isEmpty()) {
                    available = contains(nextNodeEdge, restString);
                } else { 
                    return true; // Simply return the value
                }    
            }
        }
    }
    return available;
}
```

Since you have no intention of changing it back to false once it's true, why not simply `return true`?